# C# Regular Expressions for CSS Coloring

Tags: c#, html, css, regex

I'm currently using the [FastColoredTextBox](https://github.com/PavelTorgashov/FastColoredTextBox) to create a simple `HTML/CSS` editor. While `FastColoredTextBox` comes with some predefined formatting rules for `HTML`, etc. There is not one for `CSS`. It does support custom ones though.

This is where my problem is. I'm trying to write three Regular expressions to select the selector e.g. "`div`", the attribute e.g. "`color`" and the value e.g. "`#fff`" but I can't get them to work quite right.

Does anybody have any example of `CSS` regular expressions? Or does anybody know what they should be?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Please read my question L.B.

Comment: Post your code, C#, HTML and CSS. Your question is very confusing.